# How to create rounded corners on DIV's with CSS and ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create rounded corners on my divs. I am using the standard template in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

I have followed this guide:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/rounded-corner-css-without-images.html

basicly you put this in your css file:

```
#selector {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and

```
<div id="selector">
```

Why does my site not show rounded corners on my divs? I have tried with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: We can't help you without a bit more information. The first thing to check that comes to mind is to make sure the CSS file your above code is in is actually loaded. By the sounds of things it is, but it's good to check. Another; make sure `div#selector` has content, and has a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: You'll either have to point us to your site or give us some more markup and css to work with.

Comment: @JamWaffles When i view the source i can see that the CSS file is loaded. The divs have content. @kinakuta Hmm, the site is running on my local machine, so i can't show it :/

Comment: @Nanek: Just covering all the bases :-) Could you make a quick JSFiddle to show us some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to specify a [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your CSS to this in order to display the border:

```
#selector {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in asp.net its easy to implement rounded corner to panels using ajax, try the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="AppWorkspace" Height="188px" Width="271px">
    </asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="Panel1_RoundedCornersExtender"
        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Panel1" Radius="15">
    </ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```